# How to get two values from one, point free, in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

For example, given a value, `v`, and a function `f`, is there a way to get `(f v,v)` point free?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alternatively, note that for functions `h` and `f` with appropriate types,

```
h >>= f = \w -> f (h w) w
```

so you can write

```
f >>= (,)
```

Comment: I don't think that's a tuple section, I think that's standard.

Comment: I like this since it avoids the import.

Answer (score 11):

```
import Control.Arrow
(g &&& f) v = (g v, f v)
-- ergo,
(id &&& f) v = (v, f v)
(f &&& id) v = (f v, v)
```

Comment: Or, also from `Control.Arrow`, `first` and `second`.

Answer (score 5):

How about using the `Applicative` instance for `(->)`

```
liftA2 (,) id :: (a -> b) -> a -> (a, b)
```

For example

```
liftA2 (,) id succ 5

>>> (5,6)
```