# Apply function and wrap in tuple in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am looking for a way to write a function that applies a provided function and wraps argument and function result inside a tuple. Such as:

```
applyZip :: (a -> b) -> a -> (a,b)
applyZip f x = (x, f x)
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to write this in Haskell, preferably with library code?

**Edit**:
I was just genuinely interested in other approaches to solve this. If you find your self in the same problem, implementing the function yourself with a descriptive name might be preferable.

Comment: I think your `applyZip` is good enough, but `(id &&&)` would also work (with `(&&&)` from `Control.Arrow`.

Comment: I’d say that code is already as good as it gets. Implementing the same thing with a library function would be just obfuscating, IMHO. Unless there is some higher meaning to the construct that would be made more obvious using the library function.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266825/how-to-get-two-values-from-one-point-free-in-haskell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
import Control.Monad(ap)

applyZip :: (a -> b) -> a -> (a,b)
applyZip = ap (,)
```

Here we work with the [`ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:ap) function.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more why this works? I tried for quite some time but failed. :)

Comment: @peri4n: sure, but give me some time (currently quite busy).

Comment: @peri4n `ap` in the reader monad is the S combinator, if that helps. [This type signature for it might also help:](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-aviary-0.4.0/docs/src/Data-Aviary-Functional.html#line-147) `ap :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)` (you should be able to implement this type yourself without too much thought just by "matching up types").

Comment: Equivalent without imports (in GHC 8): `applyZip = ((,) <*>)`

Comment: In real code, I'd consider this to be deliberate obfuscation. :-P (+1)